# time complexity of a recursion function where recursion appears twice

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

I want to find the time complexity of this function using [repeating substition method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ob8SM0fz6p0) . I know it goes something like this

T(n) = 2T(n/2) + Θ(1)
=2^2T(n/2^2) + 2Θ(1) + Θ(1)
.
.
.
=nΘ(1) + (2^k-1)Θ(1)

and the result is O(n).I just don't understand why the end result is O(n). Where did it come from?

```
void foo(int n){ 
    if(n>1){ 
        foo(n/2); 
        foo(n/2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image the number  to be represented by a line of  marbles:

```
⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫
```

The first recursive call will deal with one half of those, while the other recursive call will deal with the other half:

```
⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫|⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫⚫
```

And each of those recursive calls will do the same:

```
⚫⚫⚫⚫|⚫⚫⚫⚫|⚫⚫⚫⚫|⚫⚫⚫⚫
```

So it continues until the base case:

```
⚫|⚫|⚫|⚫|⚫|⚫|⚫|⚫|⚫|⚫|⚫|⚫|⚫|⚫|⚫|⚫
```

Sometimes the number of marbles will be odd, and then we can imagine that the middle marble will be excluded from recursive calls.

So the base case will be executed at most  times: once for each marble. This is O().